# Ansible opens hundreds of SSH connections instead of reusing a single one

Tags: ssh, ansible, connection-pooling

I have a simple-ish ansible playbook which deploys some software on remote hosts. When I run it with `-vvv` I see hundreds of the following messages:

```
[2020-04-07 17:22:29] <54.234.19.60> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: centos
```

Each of those will take around half a second for a total of several minutes per deployment.

How do I make Ansible open a single SSH connection per host when work is started, do all of its operations through this connection, close it when all work is done?

Comment: This sounds like a strong candidate for Mitogen: https://mitogen.networkgenomics.com/ansible_detailed.html

Comment: @MattSchuchard Mitogen seems to work OK, but run time difference is modest. Still, maybe it will make sense to add an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding:

```
[ssh_connection]
pipelining = True
```

in `ansible.cfg`

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/ssh_connection.html#parameter-pipelining

Additionally you can try adding ControlPersist:

```
[ssh_connection]
pipelining = True
control_path = /tmp/ansible-ssh-%%h-%%p-%%r
#or simply:
#control_path = /tmp
```

to the same section in the cfg file.

Comment: Unfortunately, it did not help, I still see individual SSH commands in the terminal all the time :(

Comment: But after all changes it seems to pass faster indeed. I have also increased `connect_timeout = 120`

Comment: Well there might be many other factors, like connection speed, network, CPU/Memory of the executing machine.. it's connectivity.. other configs.. :)